# CodeIgniter keeps returning an empty array in DB query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a two dimensional array which contains information about parent-cateogries (`parent=1`). Here is a `print_r()` of this array:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => parent2
            [content] => this is an example
            [avator] => 
            [thumnail] => 
            [parent] => 1
            [parent_id] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => THISPARENT
            [content] => A NOTE
            [avator] => 
            [thumnail] => 
            [parent] => 1
            [parent_id] => 12
        )

)
```

In this array I have two parents. Only one of them has already a child in database table, so when I search the Database for a child wholse parent_id should be one of the two, a logical result should be an array with the information of one child category, while it returns two arrays, one of which is empty.

I search the DB using the above parent-cateogries' ids by using the below `loop`:

```
  for($i=0; $i<count($cats); $i++)
        {
            $this->db->where("parent_id", $cats[$i]['id']);
            $res = $this->db->get("category");  
            $x[$i] = $res->result_array(); 
        }
```

Now, what I do receive as result is here:

```
                    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [title] => child
                    [content] => childparent it is
                    [avator] => 
                    [thumnail] => 
                    [parent] => 0
                    [parent_id] => 3
                )

        )

)
```

While there should not be an empty zero-indexed array, I only expect to receive on array which I have already as the second index, the first empty! Why?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving zero-indexed array because of

```
$x[$i] = $res->result_array();
```

Try to change it to

```
$results = $res->result_array();
if (is_array($results) && count($results)>0) {
  $x[$i] = $results; 
}
```

Then it should skip zero-indexed and all empty arrays.

Comment: thanks I will check it tonight and report the result